# Is there any clan/individual with extraordinary hearing ability to sense people in Naruto?

Tags: naruto

I know that there are sensory type ninja who could sense others using eye (Byakugan users), nose (Kakashi, Kiba's clan members) and chakra based sensing (Karin and others). Is there anyone/clan who can sense based on sound? Like sensing blasts in a certain range or eavesdropping others etc.

Comment: Do you want just kekkei genkai or do you want any clans?

Answer (score 1):

None that I know of, no. I don't think there was ever one in the fillers either.

The only thing close I can think of is **[Dosu Kinuta](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dosu_Kinuta)** of the sound village, he used to attack using sound.